# Number of cycles in complete graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

How many number of cycles are there in a complete graph?

Is there any relation to Symmetric group?

Comment: Cycles or induced cycles?

Comment: It's an induced subgraph isomorphic to a cycle graph.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph

Comment: In a complete graph, a subgraph consisting of three points is an induced cycle, but any larger subgraph is not.

Comment: I dont understand. I know that any 3 points of $K_n$ is a cycle. What is an induced cycle here?

Comment: @Turbo An induced subgraph is the subgraph formed from a set of vertices and all edges between them.  An induced cycle is an induced subgraph that is a cycle.  For a complete graph, given any $k$ vertices the induced subgraph is $K_k$, which is only a cycle if $k=3$.

Answer (score 17):

We can use some group theory to count the number of cycles of the graph $K_k$ with $n$ vertices.  First note that the symmetric group $S_k$ acts on the complete graph by permuting its vertices.  It's clear that you can send any $n$-cycle to any other $n$-cycle via this action, so we say that $S_k$ acts transitively on the $n$-cycles.  The orbit-stabilizer theorem states that the order of a group acting transitively on a set, is the product of the size of the set and the size of the subgroup stabilizing an element of the set.  In this case, we can stabilize an $n$-cycle by permuting the $k-n$ vertices not involved in the cycle, and then permuting the $n$ vertices in the cycle in a way that preserves the cycle.  This gives us that the cycle stabilizer has size $(k-n)!\cdot 2n.$  Now we have $$|S_k| = (\text{number of n-cycles})((k-n)!\cdot 2n). $$ hence the number of $n$-cycles is $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!\cdot 2n}$.  The total number of cycles can be computed as a sum: $$\sum_{i=3}^k \frac{k!}{(k-i)!\cdot 2i}.$$ I'm not sure whether this sum simplifies.

Here the group theory doesn't add much to the counting, over the usual overcounting-and-dividing solution to this type of problem.  However it demonstrates that this technique is a special case of a more general result, and gives a concrete example with which to understand it.

Comment: Are you looking at only simple cycles?

Comment: Yes this is only considering simple cycles.  Non simple cycles can also be counted, but require a different technique - one approach employs some linear algebra.  I'd be glad to elaborate.

Comment: This is the number of *undirected* simple cycles. The term "cycle" can also be used for *directed* simple cycles (in an undirected graph), of which there are twice as many. (See the distinction made at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29.) This corresponds to two OEIS sequences, [A002807](https://oeis.org/A002807) for undirected cycles and [A119913](https://oeis.org/A119913) for directed cycles. If you omit the $2$ (i.e. count directed cycles) and include the terms for $i=1,2$ in the sum, you get [A002104](https://oeis.org/A002104), the logarithmic numbers.

Comment: I think answer is wrong. Number of $k$ cycles is $\binom{n}{k-1}(k-1)!+\binom{n-1}{k-1}(k-1)!+\dots+\binom{k-1}{k-1}(k-1)! =\Big(\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{k-1}{k-1}\Big)(k-1)!$.

Answer (score 13):

From $K_n$ lets pick a number $p$, $p \le n$ where $C_p$ is a cycle of length $p$.

Let $2\to 3\to 4\to 5\to 1\to\dots\to (p-1)\to 2$ be any arbitrary $C_p$. (note that the first and last vertex are same).

Now we fix the first vertex(which is also the last vertex since it is a cycle) like:
$$
2\to [3\to 4\to 5\to 1\to\dots\to (p-1)]\to 2
$$
We have $(p-1)!/2$ different cycles if we permute the section within the square brackets '$[]$' (circular permutation).

Now, from $K_n$ we can choose $p$ vertex in $\dbinom np$ ways and each of the $p$ vertex has $(p-1)!/2$ cycles.

Therefore the total number of cycles in $K_n$ is 
$$
\sum_{p=3}^{n} \binom np \frac{(p-1)!}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In a complete graph, every choice of n vertices is a cycle, so if the graph has k vertices, then there is $\sum_{n=3}^{k} {k \choose n}$, which is equal to $  \dfrac{-k^2}{2}-\dfrac{k}{2}+2^k-1$. As for the symmetric group, I'm pretty sure that it is the automorphism group for the complete graph of the same size.

Comment: Order is somewhat important. A subset of 4 vertices forms 3 cycles of length 4.