# Number of Cycles in a Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

I was working on a program that involved finding the optimal route that runs through various interconnecting vertices, and I decided to implement the brute force method that runs through every possible loop and simply returns the shortest (this is O(N!)).

I realized that if, for example, there are three vertices (let's say each vertex is identified by an integer), then 1,2,3 and 2,3,1 and 3,1,2 are all the same loop just starting at a different place. Likewise, 3,2,1 is the same loop just backwards.

It got me thinking, given a set of N elements, each interconnected, how many possible loops can be formed? Also, what is this branch of mathematics/question called?

Comment: Do you mean [cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html) rather then [loop](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphLoop.html)?

Comment: In fact any permutation of node labels represents a common loop. On a 2D surface some permutations will involve crossovers (edge from 1 to 3 crosses the edge from 2 to 4), but that's just an artifact of how the graph is displayed (although if the graph represents something that is inherently 2D, then ignore this) BTW, depending on what "optimal" means, this is just the traveling salesman problem. Searching for info on that problem may yield a less CPU intensive implementation for your program.

Comment: @Χpẘ Yes, it is just the traveling salesman problem. The point, I guess, is that it got me curious on how many repeated iterations it has. We know ahead of time that identical cycles in different directions or starting from different points will have the same length, but we iterate through them along with new ones anyways. My program was just a homework that expects the standard "brute force" approach, but it made me curious about the math beneath it, and what effect this inefficiency has.

Comment: @Smylic Yes. The reason that I asked this question is precisely that I am unknowledgeable on the topic, and unaware as to how to refer to things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363963/number-of-cycles-in-complete-graph) is a nice argument for the number of cycles in $K_{n}$ of length $k$ using the orbit-stabilizer theorem. If you sum this across all $0\leq k\leq n$, you get the number of distinct cycles in $K_{n}$.